# JSON correct construction

Tags: shell-script, json

I'm generating a JSON file with a shell script but I can't find a solution to automatically get rid of the last comma just before the ending "}".

Here is my code:

```
echo "{" >> out_file
for i in 3 4 5 6 7 #ends at 298
do
y=$i
sommeMag=`awk -F '=' '/'$y'/{sommeMag+=$2}END{print sommeMag}'` "/myfolder/... "
store="mag$y"
if [ -z "$sommeMag" ] #checks is variable is empty
    then
        echo  "\"" $store"\"":0",">> out_file
    else
        echo "\""$store"\"":$sommeMag"," >> out_file
    fi
done
echo "}" >> out_file
```

The file is ending this way :

```
{
" mag297":0,
" mag298":0, <-- syntaxt error
}
```

The file should end this way :

```
{
...
" mag297":0,
" mag298":0 <-- no more comma
}
```

How can I manage that?

The code has been edited to be more readable here.

Comment: show how should look the whole result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest edited my post

Comment: 1) use echo -n to omit new line when printing variable. 2) have a comma var initialize after first loop and printed before each var.

Comment: Do you really have to use shell scripts ? I mean, other tools like python or perl could deal with it much better

Comment: There are many better solutions than to manually craft JSON from shell strings.  Unfortunately, you never say what your `awk` code is supposed to be doing or what the files that you parse contain, so it' a bit difficult to provide a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

What you should be doing is printing first item, and let the cursor stop. Then you can start working on the loop and advance the cursor by inserting comma and newline. `printf` is more helpful than echo in that regard. To prevent excessive repetition and shorten the code, use functions.

Since I don't have the files you're parsing with awk, i can't work with your script but the example below illustrates what I'm trying to convey.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

print_entry(){
    # sommeMag would be variable $2, $1 is store
    if [ -z $2 ]
    then
        printf '"%s":0' "$1" 
    else
        printf '"%s":%s' "$1" "$2"
    fi
}

# main part of the script
printf "%s\n" "{"

# do the first one unconditionally but without comma
print_entry "something1" "something2"
for i in 2 3 4 5
do
    # because first one was printed unconditionally
    # now we just keep printing comma and moving cursor
    # to newline to insert the new entry
    printf ",\n"
    print_entry "something$i" "$i"
done
printf "\n%s"  "}"
```

Sample run

```
$ ./make_json.sh                                                                                                                                      
{
"something1":something2,
"something2":2,
"something3":3,
"something4":4,
"something5":5
}$
```

---

The above approach is typically what I call "add comma behind". Another approach would be "Add comma ahead", but instead of for loop, use `while` loop with counter to simulate C-style for loop behavior. If you reach last item, don't output comma. Basically

```
counter=1
while [ $counter -le 298 ]
do
    $json_value=$(command1)
    if [ $counter -ne 298  ]
    then
        echo $json_value ,
    else
        echo $json_value
    fi 
    $counter=$(($counter+1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#
# var initialzizations
#
# newline
NL=`printf '\nn'`;NL=${NL%?}

# double quote
q=\"

# separator set to a comma+newline
sep=",$NL"

# container for the json result
json=;

# begin/end of count values
start=3
 stop=7

# looping
# in case seq utility not found, then you can use: yes | sed -ne "$start,$stop=;${stop}q"
for i in `seq "$start" "$stop"`
do
   y=$i
   sommeMag=`awk -F = "/$y/"'{sommeMag+=$2}END{print sommeMag}'` "/myfolder/... "
   store=mag$y
   json=${json:-}${json:+"$sep"}$q\ $store$q:${sommeMag:-0}
done

# remove the separtor from the end and also place a newline
json=${json%"$sep"}$NL

printf '{\n%s}\n' "$json" >> out_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a stream of tab-delimited key and value pairs, construct a single JSON object containing those keys and values.  (If the data contains actual tabs, simply use a character that is not part of the data.)

```bash
for something something
do
    output key and value with a tab in-between
done |
jq -Rn 'reduce inputs as $line ({}; ($line|split("\t")) as [$key, $value] | . += {($key): $value})'
```

This uses `jq` to read a stream of lines, each with a key and a value separated by a tab character.  Each line is read and used as `$line` in the `jq` expression.  It is split on the tab character, and the key and value are added to the object that the `reduce` statement is accumulating.  The object grows as new keys and values are added, and when the input stream ends, the finished object is outputted.

This is a pretty-printed version of the `jq` expression:

```
reduce inputs as $line ({}; 
    ($line | split("\t")) as [$key, $value] | 
    . += {($key): $value}
)
```

A working example script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for (( i = 1; i <= 10; ++i ))
do
        printf 'key%.2d\tvalue%.2d\n' "$i" "$i"
done |
jq -Rn 'reduce inputs as $line ({}; ($line|split("\t")) as [$key, $value] | . += {($key): $value})'
```

Output:

```json
{
  "key01": "value01",
  "key02": "value02",
  "key03": "value03",
  "key04": "value04",
  "key05": "value05",
  "key06": "value06",
  "key07": "value07",
  "key08": "value08",
  "key09": "value09",
  "key10": "value10"
}
```

If there aren't too many key and values, we can simplify this and just create a very long `jq` command line that associates each key with its value using `--arg`, and then ask `jq` to output these (which will be found in the internal `$ARGS.named` structure):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

args=()
for (( i = 1; i <= 10; ++i ))
do
        printf -v key   'key%.2d'   "$i"
        printf -v value 'value%.2d' "$i"
        args+=( --arg "$key" "$value" )
done

jq -n "${args[@]}" '$ARGS.named'
```

In this case, the output will be identical to the output of the earlier script.  The difference is that the number of keys and values the earlier script can cope with is limited by the memory available to the `jq` process. In contrast, this variant is limited by the maximum allowed length of the command line, which is usually much smaller.  On the upside, this most recent script will cope with values containing any character, including newlines.